# nfsstat -s: What does sequence mean?

Tags: centos, nfs

I am having a lot of trouble with my NFS v4 server running over infiniband (IPoIB), every time the load gets high, the nfs server locks up and I have to reboot the server to fix the problem. I get the following messages every few seconds:

```
Message from syslogd@fruster at Jul 14 12:51:54 ...
  kernel:BUG: soft lockup - CPU#6 stuck for 22s! [nfsd:15806]
```

I have been trying to debug this and figure out what is going on, and so I checked `nfsstat -s` to see what was using all of the bandwidth:

```
Server rpc stats:
calls      badcalls   badclnt    badauth    xdrcall
241998732   0          0          0          0       

Server nfs v4:
null         compound     
3         0% 242004087 99% 

Server nfs v4 operations:
op0-unused   op1-unused   op2-future   access       close        commit       
0         0% 0         0% 0         0% 148697    0% 65006     0% 124611    0% 
create       delegpurge   delegreturn  getattr      getfh        link         
3072      0% 0         0% 10373     0% 6028483   2% 120565    0% 0         0% 
lock         lockt        locku        lookup       lookup_root  nverify      
0         0% 0         0% 0         0% 52306     0% 0         0% 0         0% 
open         openattr     open_conf    open_dgrd    putfh        putpubfh     
90478     0% 0         0% 223       0% 18760     0% 18834351  6% 0         0% 
putrootfh    read         readdir      readlink     remove       rename       
65        0% 12579510  4% 4540      0% 5         0% 24848     0% 20232     0% 
renew        restorefh    savefh       secinfo      setattr      setcltid     
23413     0% 0         0% 20241     0% 0         0% 1073      0% 66        0% 
setcltidconf verify       write        rellockowner bc_ctl       bind_conn    
66        0% 0         0% 5716220   2% 0         0% 0         0% 13        0% 
exchange_id  create_ses   destroy_ses  free_stateid getdirdeleg  getdevinfo   
101       0% 159       0% 58        0% 0         0% 0         0% 0         0% 
getdevlist   layoutcommit layoutget    layoutreturn secinfononam sequence     
0         0% 0         0% 0         0% 0         0% 0         0% 225439523 83% 
set_ssv      test_stateid want_deleg   destroy_clid reclaim_comp 
0         0% 0         0% 0         0% 0         0% 55        0%
```

As you can see, 'sequence' is using 83% of the NFS bandwidth, but I have no idea what 'sequence' is, and I can't find it online anywhere because when I search for 'nfsstat -s output sequence' I get a bunch of pages telling me to 'do the following steps in sequence'.

Does anyone have any idea what 'sequence' is? Bonus points if you have a suggestion as to why NFS is freezing up.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definition appears to be as below.

[RFC 3530 NFS v4 : Network File System (NFS) version 4 Protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3530)

**NFS4ERR_BAD_SEQID**
The sequence number in a locking request is neither the next expected number or the last number processed.

The [source for nfsstat](http://fossies.org/linux/nfs-utils/utils/nfsstat/nfsstat.c) didn't reveal any more info unfortunately.

**UPDATE 15th July** : Possibility of [Bug 651409 - BAD SEQID error messages returned by the NFS server](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=651409) being the culprit here.

Comment: Thanks @steve, thats great. Now I just need to figure out why I am getting so many out of sequence locking requests.

Answer (score 0):

This is Operation 53 of NFSv4.1

> The SEQUENCE operation is used by the server to implement session
> request control and the reply cache semantics.

[Source](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5661#page-553)

The operation itself doesn't seem to indicate any error or problem.